# При установке SASS в OC Windows выдает данную ошибку

Tags: windows, sass, install

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2017. Все права защищены.

C:\Users\vladi>gem install sass
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
        The last version of ffi (< 2, >= 0.5.0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.9.18. Try installing it with `gem install ffi -v 1.9.18` and then running the current command again
        ffi requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.

Мне ответили разные версии. Так вот вопрос разные версии чего ? И помогите от начало до конца решить данную проблему.